# how to open model popup on textbox click

Tags: asp.net

I want to open modelpopup only when my checkbox is checked and user clicks on textbox.but how to find checkbox in this

for this i wrote,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#x").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 200,
      width: 500,
      modal: true
    });
    $("#y").click(function() {
      $("#x").dialog("open");
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

where x->id which should be opened in popup
y->textbox id

Answer (score 2):

You can locate your check box from its `id` attribute and use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to determine if it is checked:

```
$(function() {
    $("#x").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
        modal: true
    });
    $("#y").click(function() {
        if ($("#yourCheckBoxId").is(":checked")) {
            $("#x").dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how to find checkbox and use :checked selector

Comment: `$("#yourCheckBoxId").is(":checked")`. Do you mean your check box has no id?